# My program throws an error when trying to run my function

Tags: python

I tried to make a function that checks if my Ubuntu Server has a specific package installed via apt list, when the condition isn't met it, in theory, the program should install any necessary dependencies for the other piece of software to work. Here's a function I wrote:

```
# Docker Configuration Tool
def DCT():
    cache = apt.Cache()
    if cache['docker-ce'].is_installed:
        print("Docker and Docker-compose are installed on this system...")
        print("If you don't have MySQL Server installed on your system use Docker to prepare and configure your Server")
        __run_file = [ BASH COMMANDS ]
        OS_MCE(__run_file)
    else:
        print("Docker and Docker-compose are not installed on this system!")
        print("Preparing Environment for the Installation...\n")

        __install_docker = [ BASH COMMANDS ]
        OS_MCE(__install_docker)
```

An error when trying to run this function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MIM.py", line 304, in <module>
    NSWIT(True)
  File "MIM.py", line 297, in NSWIT
    Menu()
  File "MIM.py", line 257, in Menu
    DCT()
  File "MIM.py", line 117, in DCT
    if cache['docker-ce'].is_installed:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 305, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError('The cache has no package named %r' % key)
KeyError: "The cache has no package named 'docker-ce'"
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty darn clear.  You're trying to access the `docker-ce` key in the `cache` map, and no such key exists, so the map throws an exception.   Maybe you want to first check for the existence of the key.  So replace `if cache['docker-ce'].is_installed:` with  `if 'docker-ce' in cache and cache['docker-ce'].is_installed:` ?

Comment: The idea is that it shouldn't find the package hence the if else statement. I want the program to run additional commands to install the said package.

Comment: should I use throw and catch statement to circumvent the exception?

Comment: Yes.  I would think that the change I suggest might give you that.  I think it will lead to execution of the `else` case rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: You mean try/catch...you could, but I don't think you need to .  Just change that one line to what I gave you above and you should be good.

Comment: yeah that is the one. Haven't used these statements in a while lol. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure.  I went ahead and added this advice as an answer, mostly so I could show you just what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `if` expression to check that the `docker-ce` key is in the `cache` map before trying to access it.  If there isn't a key with that name, it makes sense to assume that the package isn't installed.  So like this:

```
# Docker Configuration Tool
def DCT():
    cache = apt.Cache()
    if 'docker-ce' in cache and cache['docker-ce'].is_installed:
        print("Docker and Docker-compose are installed on this system...")
        print("If you don't have MySQL Server installed on your system use Docker to prepare and configure your Server")
        __run_file = [ BASH COMMANDS ]
        OS_MCE(__run_file)
    else:
        print("Docker and Docker-compose are not installed on this system!")
        print("Preparing Environment for the Installation...\n")

        __install_docker = [ BASH COMMANDS ]
        OS_MCE(__install_docker)
```

Error messages are your friend.  Read them carefully.  In this case, the error was telling you precisely what was wrong, and with that, it is obvious how to fix it once you've been doing this for a while.

This is a good opportunity to learn about and understand short-circuited evaluation of logical expressions.  The first clause of your conditional expression insures that the second clause isn't evaluated if it will throw the error you were seeing (well, Duh!, right?)...but if you don't fully understand why that is, it's a good thing to clearly understand.  Maybe see: https://pythoninformer.com/python-language/intermediate-python/short-circuit-evaluation/

Comment: Thank you again! As you might've noticed, I'm quite new to Python, so I'm still learning a lot of new things.